# How to enable YSlow in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, yslow

I have installed the latest versions of YSlow and Firebug into the latest version of Firefox on Windows 7 (and restarted Firefox), but when I click on YSlow nothing happens.  Also, when I click on Firebug, it opens but has no YSlow tab.  I have disabled all other Firefox plugins and played with right-clicking YSlow and clicking run once and auto-run.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would there be any version conflicts between firebug and yslow?

Comment: I've been having this same exact problem. When I remove/disable YSlow and then install/activate it, it works... but only until I close Firefox again.

Comment: The author has asked for help with Firebug/Firefox as it no longer works https://twitter.com/yslow/status/596009262490464256/photo/1

Comment: problem with me is that I don't see the YSlow pluging icon at all from where I can activate it for usage. I'm on firefox 47.x

Comment: YSlow seems to have got broken inside firebug extension in latest firefox release as evident from this tweet  https://twitter.com/yslow/status/596009262490464256

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a temporary solution, try using the [YSlow bookmarklet](http://yslow.org/mobile/).

It's an equivalent of regular YSlow.

Comment: most unique thing about ySlow while searching it in google chrome extension list is that it is not at all searchable in chrome web store :-). I wonder why is that. But you can get it using this link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yslow/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh

Answer (score 0):

Try running Firefox in Safe Mode and disable other plugins that may conflict with YSlow. Also ensure you have really restarted Firefox.

Comment: did you mean start firefox in safe mode - it disables the plugins that way - didnt work

Comment: Please clarify this answer with some more detail, otherwise someone will probably downvote you.  Because you're new, I won't :-)  Take into account what has been said in the comment by the poster.

Comment: Thanks Wayne I updated the answer. Because the answer it is no longer useful I would delete it if I could. :(

Comment: Gave you an upvote for effort.  There should be a delete link next to "edit" under the answer text, I didn't think any special amount of rep was needed to delete your own answers, but I may be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

YSlow seems to have got broken inside firebug extension in latest firefox release as evident from [this](https://twitter.com/yslow/status/596009262490464256) tweet from their official twitter handle. Try using [GTMetrix](https://twitter.com/gtmetrix) google chrome extension. It provides one of the most exhaustive web performance statistics using [PageSpeed](https://twitter.com/pagespeed) and [ySlow](https://twitter.com/yslow) both. Below I've mentioned google chrome store extension link. The only thing is that you will have to use chrome instead of firefox as your web browser.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtmetrix-plugin/maaoaegejdlcdijmlfmpmeknliggkfdm